# Get GitHub Repository Insights via GitHub GraphQL API (v4)

Tags: github, graphql, analytics, github-api, github-graphql

I want to obtain information about the number of times my projects have been viewed, cloned and where the traffic came from (individually).

I can currently view this `Traffic` information by clicking on the `Insights` button of the repository (via the web interface).

Is there a schema in the GitHub v4 GraphQL API to retrieve this information?

The closest I got was the following; `nodes`  didn't contain any sort of statistical data:

```
{
  viewer {
    repositories(first: 100) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        name
        description

      }
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
// response


{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "repositories": {
        "totalCount": 55,
        "nodes": [
          {
            "name": "Repo Name",
            "description": "Repo Description"
          },
          {
            ...
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Anyone? Anything?

Comment: Also looking for the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to retrieve traffic information using GraphQL API (as explained in [here](https://github.community/t/graphql-v4-api-traffic-types/14606)).
Alternately you can use REST API v3 as described in [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#traffic).

Please notice that reviewing traffic requires tokens with push permissions to the desired repositories.